# How do I reference line numbers in Microsoft Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I want to refer to line numbers in code which I have in my appendix. Each piece of code is in its own section where line numbers begin from 1.

I want to be able to write something like;

"With reference to line `23` in code snippet `6.8`, ..."

If I add or remove lines above the text being referenced or if I change the margins or font size such that wrapping causes lines to be created or destroyed, then I want the line number reference to update just like a *numbered item* reference would update if the chapter numbers change.

What I've tried so far:

1. I checked in the cross-references section of Word 2013 but wasn't able to find a *line number* reference type. Can I create such a reference type?
2. I tried simply selecting the entire code section and turning it into a numbered list, which I could then reference, but that bungles on line wrapping and indented code. Also it would be a bit of work setting up the styles and it would be much cleaner to use Word's built-in line numbering tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately word doesn't have a way to generate cross-references to line numbers. You might have some luck creating a complex VBA macro that would satisfy this requirement, but most likely a better idea is to just rethink how you want to display your cross-references.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a very simple solution: You can cross-reference numbered items in Word. Create yourself a style, e.g. "Code" and use numbering on it. Write your code using that style.

Then, try to insert a cross-reference, reference type: "Numbered item". In the list of the pop-up, you will see all lines of code you have written throughout your document. In the "Insert reference to" field you can choose "page number" to only get the line number.

[image: Screenshot: Word: cross-reference to numbered item]

Comment: I moved your image to inline rather than as a link. You can do this yourself when posting using the picture icon.  Your solution would work OK for the first instance of code but would be confusing with multiple instances of code.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I don't have enough points here to post images... Why would it be confusing with multiple instances of code? You can always choose "Set Numbering Value..." and have new code start with "line 1" again. Of course, the list (in the pop-up) gets larger and larger but this is better than having no option at all to achieve this.

Comment: It would be confusing because there would be multiples of 1, 2, 3, etc. i was not aware that the image icon was not available to new posters.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Yeah, but still thanks for replacing the link with the image.
With regards to the numbering: of course, that could be a bit irritating when writing the document but I am willing to pay this small price. And for the end-document it's quite usual that every code sample starts with "1" again. It's just in the list in the pop-up that it might get a bit confusing.